# Migrate Parse Users to Firebase Auth Users

Tags: parse-platform, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm needing to migrate Parse users over to Firebase Auth Users. What are best practices to transfer Passwords so that the password will still work for my users? #AskFirebase

Comment: Have you tried http://bettysteger.com/blog/2016/migrating-users-from-parse-to-firebase/ ?? Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

One good way of doing this would be to use the [Firebase command line](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) tool to batch import users. It takes in a data file with your users (csv or json) and supports many popular password hashes so your users can continue to use their accounts normally.